# The sender’s email address uses abnormal characters, which might be used to spoof real addresses. Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments.Amazon

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, gmail, warnings

Gmail shows a red banner above email messages sent from my custom email. And I have registered the domain. my domain name contains a special character (-). And this issue is for the email is also from the domain, I am using AMAZON`S SES for email services.

All other mail domains not showing this error/warning message.
both emails and domains are verified.
all other mailboxes and web versions are not showing this warning
Only exists when sending mail b/w my custom domain

Comment: I have run into exactly the same issue and I wondered if you ever got to the bottom of this?